# Fuse box replacement - will it work?

Tags: electrical, fuse

As per the advice of my mechanic, I am replacing the engine fuse box of my 2011 Mazda 6 3.7L V6.

I have ordered a fuse box from a donor vehicle - a 2011 Mazda 6 with a 2.5L 4-cyl engine.

The only difference I see between in the fuse setups between the 2.5L model and the 3.7L V6 model is that fuse #26 in the following diagram is rated at 10 amps for the 2.5L model and 20 amps for the 3.7L model, according to [this page on autogenius](https://www.autogenius.info/mazda-6-2011-2013-fuse-box-diagram/).

[image: fuse box diagram]

Offerings of this replacement both from eBay and multiple auto recyclers' inventories lists both the 2011-2013 2.5L and 3.7L models as valid applications.

Are there any potential differences in the fuse boxes themselves between these two models? Is fuse 26 the only thing I will have to swap out on the fuse box of the donor vehicle?

Comment: Do you still have all of your fuses?  you're just replacing the box?  I can't say with certainty regarding this vehicle, but typically a model of car will share the same physical box between all of its trims/engines in a given year.

Comment: @Zshoulders I have most of the fuses from the old box, and the new box will have all of its fuses.

Comment: Then I think you should be good to go.  Just use the Fuses for your car, not the 2.5L.  Anywhere there is a difference, go with what yours has/had.

Comment: @Zshoulders that's a good answer.  Why don't you stick it in the answer block below? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most* production cars, the physical fuse box(s) will be identical across different trims and engines.  Most of the fuses/relays are likely the same as well, as many parts requiring fusing are common regardless of trim or engine.

As long as you use the correct fuses and relays for your vehicle where any difference exists, you should be just fine.

*Keyword most; I'm sure exceptions exist.